# How to send this signal to a mixer?

Tags: audio, impedance-matching, receiver, mixer, ir-receiver

I have the receiver

[image]

which works when I wire a Hifi on the output. But when I try to send the signal to the port 2/3 of the following mixer

[image]

then I don't have any signal anymore. I guess I need to adapt the impedances (the receiver has a low output impedance while the mixer has a high entry impedance ?) ? How can I modify the circuit to do so ? Would someone have a good book for beginners explaining the basics on audio circuits please ? I always need tips like that

Comment: *I guess I need to adapt the impedances* No, a low output impedance and a high input impedance is normal and used in 90% (my guess) of all audio connections. What you do have is a **DC voltage** at the output of your circuit and the mixer might not like that. Probably the "HiFi" already has in input coupling capacitor which blocks the DC. So try adding a 10 uF **capacitor** in series with the opamp's output and try again.

Comment: I tried, it still works on the hifi but not for the mixer :(

Comment: Asking for tips, references, and advise on modifications for this random circuit you likely found online isn’t the best way to ask an engineer on how to improve a project. We don’t know anything about your target specifications, we don’t know anything about this mixer. Saying that something doesn’t work (i.e. in your case, “don’t have a signal”) isn’t descriptive enough for us to troubleshoot and help you. Have you taken any measurements? Is there some specific information that you’re looking for? You haven’t identified an issue.

Comment: Try sending a regular signal to the mixer to prove you have it set up correctly (should be a no-brainer of course but we don't know the size of your brain).

Comment: Yes I did and it works fine

Comment: How is it connected to the mixer? If you are connecting a single-ended output to the "hot" leg of a balanced input, you must connect the output's 0V to the "cold" leg (as well as GND) on the mixer.  Assuming the mixer has balanced inputs : if it's a cheapo it might not.

Comment: Does it not work on ANY of the input channels?  How about if you patch into the RCA jacks (aux in).    What size blocking cap did you try (as discussed about).   Audio frequencies you'll need to be in the 10-100uF range or bigger

Comment: I'm connecting with (mono) regular jack wires. I tried with 10uF and 100uF and this does not changes. I tried the RCA jack aux in, and other spots and it does not work. I tried the mic spot, and with maximal gain and volume we hear a little bit the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jom, this is an excellent opportunity to learn troubleshooting skills.

When troubleshooting, you work your way through step-by-step, considering possibilities and gathering data to rule them out or in. (Doctors work this way too -- I should know, I've had careers as an engineer and a doctor).

You've confirmed that your circuit puts out sound by connecting it to a HiFi amp, then you connected it to the ZMX52 at port 2/3 and, no sound. You tried a series capacitor because of excellent advice from @Bimpelrekkie, that your circuit puts out a strong DC level.

Have you considered the possibility that your first attempt, connecting it to ZMX52 without blocking the DC, damaged the input stage of the mixer? Rule that out by connecting another known good source to that same input and confirming there's output.

What are other possibilities that are not obvious? Could your circuit have an intermittent connection that came loose during your experimentation? Could the ZMX  input have a loose connection (those phone jacks are notorious for corroding)? Could the ZMX have much lower gain than your HiFi amp?  Rule these out. Think of other possibilities. When you solve it, you'll have learned something.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your positive help attitude :) you got it ! it's the connection of the jack in the spot that is loose, i need to get it half out... although the mixer is new